# Android - How to support multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

I was trying to make a simple application with a login form.

My problem is that it looks good on a Nexus 4 but on a Nexus 5 or Nexus 7 the layout is not what I want...

[Nexus 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ2Sp.png)

[Nexus 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PkGN.png)

What do I need to do to make a layout that works on Nexus S, Nexus 4, 5, 7, etc..?

XML

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.Log"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_log">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_amob" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:background="@color/AMOB_yellow"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="@color/AMOB_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_recuperarPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:text="Recuperar Password"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_noAccount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="No Account yet? Register here!"
                android:background="#ff0000"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: Have you at least gone through the training section in the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The attributes `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` determine the UI component size, obvius. Sometimes you should set them to `wrap_content` or `match_parent`, not fixed size, to them adapt to device screen size.

A quick look in your layout, i'd set `android:layout_width` to `match_parent`,

**Before**

`android:layout_width="368dp"`

**After**

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: thanks. Basically I can never set a width and height with a fixed number right?

Comment: It's up to your design, in some cases you should put a fixed value, but to be ok in other devices or you consider use relative layouts like `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc... or make `View`s auto adjustables according to the width and height.

Comment: In  Layout Editor of Android Studio, you can pick different devices, to check the layout behavior according to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library rather than DP.

Also, use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout rather than ConstraintLayout